# How to store .raw or raw bytes of pictures to local disk documents folder without png or jpeg representation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, avcapturesession, nsdocumentdirectory

I want to store the raw bytes of a captured picture using AVCaptureSession. But I have only seen examples of pngrepresentation and jpegrepresentation. I want to store the raw data bytes in local disk documents of phone so it can be reopened at other times and converted into a UIImage for post processing. Is there a way to do this?
for example:

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
GLubyte *rawImageBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
```

Can I store rawImageBytes in documents to open it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. Create an `NSData` object containing your bytes and save that using one of the `NSData` file saving methods (e.g. `writeToURL:atomically:`.)

You'll need to know the number of bytes in your pixelBuffer though. It looks like you should use `CVPixelBufferGetDataSize` to get the number of bytes.

Comment: What file extension would I use for the URL? .dat?

Comment: Whatever is appropriate to your needs. You're going to be the one consuming the file, so you can use an extension of ".xyz" if you want, as long as you write the code that reads the file to look for a file with that extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! I wasn't too sure how the file system storing works initially, I got a solution to work!